# Classify all graphs on finitely many nodes such that all pairs of distinct nodes share a unique (additional) neighbor

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph such that $|\operatorname{vert}(G)| \in ℤ^{+} \cup \{0\}$ and $(\forall v_1, v_2 \in \operatorname{vert}(G): v_1 \neq v_2), \exists! u \in \operatorname{vert}(G): (\{v_1, u\}, \{v_2, u\} \in \operatorname{edge}(G), \& v_1 \neq u \neq v_2).$

In other words, for distinct nodes in $G$, there is always exactly one neighbor which they share. Even if the nodes are mutually adjacent already, they must have yet another neighbor which they share. Importantly, also, there must be finitely many nodes.

Classify or find all such $G$.

I have not found such a $G$ which is not one of the following: (1) the empty graph; (2)(a) the graph on one node with zero edges; (2)(b) the graph on one node with a loop (edge to itself); (3) $n$ triangles which share exactly one vertex between them all, such that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and where, for each node, we toggle whether that node has a loop to itself. Examples of the last class: the triangle graph (complete graph on three nodes), two triangles which share exactly one vertex (bowtie), three triangles which meet exactly at a single central node (nuclear radiation symbol), four triangles meeting like a windmill propeller. Are there any others?

I do not know of typical techniques with which I can attempt to discover such classes or to prove that I have discovered them all. Guidance in this regard would be at least as valuable as the direct answer.

Finiteness seems to be key.

Also, it is trivial to show that the graph-geodesic distance between two (not necessarily mutually-distinct) nodes in $G$ is at most 2.

Comment: Another comment -- are loops allowed in simple graphs?

Comment: Interesting question, but maybe you should clarify a bit what you mean by "classify or find" all such graphs...what you have given is already a classification, and if we interpret "find" to mean collect them in a set, then you can just make the set of graphs satisfying your condition...but from the examples you gave, it sounds like you might be more interested in finding an algorithm for constructing all such graphs for a given number of nodes, or perhaps a shorthand way of determining whether a graph satisfies this. Either way, you will need to clarify what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @walkar The definitions which I have seen for "simple" graph state that every pair of nodes have either 0 or 1 edges which mutually connect them. By this definition, loops are allowed. If the nodes in the pair must be mutually distinct, then loops are prohibited. Not a big deal either way.

Comment: @Carlyle It is moot because Sudix seems to have proven that my classification is complete but: I did mean "classify" in the sense which you specified. The goal was to get a complete classification. The issue is that I was not sure that I managed to do so. I conjectured that I had, but did not know it. So, I wanted to prove my classification or to find the graphs which were missing from it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I checked Diestel's graph theory book, and he defines it to be loopless... But I suppose it doesn't affect the question much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $G$ has $n\ge 2$ nodes. Let further the vertices of $G$ be $v_1,...,v_n$. Let further the shared neighbors of $G$ also be named $n_1,...,n_k$ for some $k\in[n]$.

Let $\delta_i\in\{0,1\}^k$ for $i\in[n]$ tell us, to which shared neighbors the vertex $v_i$ has an edge, i.e.
$$\forall z\in[k]:\quad (\delta_i)_z = 1\;\Leftrightarrow\; \{v_i,n_z\}\in \text{edge}(V)$$

Then we're looking for values $\delta_1,...,\delta_n$ which solve the equation system
$$
\forall i,j\in [n]:\qquad i\neq j\Rightarrow \delta_i^T \cdot \delta_j =1
$$

If we define $\Delta:=\pmatrix{\delta_1^T\\\vdots\\ \delta_n^T}$, then this equation system also solves
$$
\Delta \Delta^T = \unicode{x1D7D9} + \text{diag}(\delta_1^T\cdot\delta_1-1,...,\delta_n^T\cdot\delta_n-1)
$$
,where $\unicode{x1D7D9}:=(1)_{(i,j)\in[k]^2}$ is the matrix that is all ones, and $\text{diag}(\delta_1^T\cdot\delta_1-1,...,\delta_n^T\cdot\delta_n-1)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now the LHS has rank $\le k$ since $\Delta\in\{0,1\}^{n\times k}$. The RHS on the other hand has rank $\ge n-1$, as each diagonal entry of the diagonal matrix is $\ge 1$.

To see this, assume that a vertex $v_i$ of $G$ had only one edge to a shared neighbor $N$ (i.e. $\delta_i$ has exactly one non-zero entry). Then, even if every other vertex of $G$ has an edge to $N$, since $v_i$ and $N$ have a shared neighbor, we arrive at the contradiction that $v_i$ has actually two edges to shared neighbors, and thus $\delta_i^T\delta_i \ge 2$.

Therefore, if there are any graphs in the class you defined, they have at least $ n-1$ shared neighbors. Let for each shared neighbor $n_i$ two of the vertices which share $n_i$ be $v_{n_i}, w_{n_i}$.

The shared neighbor $x$ of $n_i$ and $v_{n_i}$ creates a triangle. Therefore each vertex of $G$ is a part of a triangle, and because the maximum distance in the graph is 2, each pair of triangles needs to overlap in at least one vertex. But each pair of triangles also cant overlap in two vertices, because then we'd have two vertices with more than one shared neighbor. Similarly, even if we have more than 2 triangles, they all need to overlap in the same vertex, for else there'd be two vertices with more than one shared neighbor.

And with that we've proved that the listing you gave is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Any two non adjacent u, v vertices have exactly  one common neighbor, every other neighbor of u is not a neighbor of v, and vice versa. And  every other neighbor of u must be adjacent to exactly one neighbor of v, and vice versa. The only possibility is that $d(u) =d(v)$ and generally we can claim that all non adjacent vertices must have the same degree. Maybe from there, you can deduce all non adjacent vertices must have degree 2, and one vértix is connected to every vértix

You can search for Friendship Theorem for the details